# spacing (margin?/padding?) appearing between divs

Tags: html, css, margin, padding, spacing

I am trying to create a grid made up of dots, lines, and boxes (all `div` elements). For some reason it seems like they start out with something like `margin: 2px;` and setting `margin: 0px` doesn't get rid of this. Setting `-2px` gets me somewhere. But what is the deal here? Why aren't they touching?

The markup alternates between these two `div`s:

```
<div class="row_short">
    <div class="dot"></div>
    <div class="hbar"></div>
    <div class="dot"></div>
    <div class="hbar"></div>
    <div class="dot"></div>
    <div class="hbar"></div>
    <div class="dot"></div>
    <div class="hbar"></div>
    <div class="dot"></div>
    <div class="hbar"></div>
    <div class="dot"></div>
    <div class="hbar"></div>
    <div class="dot"></div>
    <div class="hbar"></div>
    <div class="dot"></div>
    <div class="hbar"></div>
    <div class="dot"></div>
    <div class="hbar"></div>
    <div class="dot"></div>
    <div class="hbar"></div>
    <div class="dot"></div>
    <div class="hbar"></div>
    <div class="dot"></div>
    <div class="hbar"></div>
    <div class="dot"></div>
    <div class="hbar"></div>
    <div class="dot"></div>
</div>
<div class="row_tall">
    <div class="vbar"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="vbar"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="vbar"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="vbar"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="vbar"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="vbar"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="vbar"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="vbar"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="vbar"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="vbar"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="vbar"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="vbar"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="vbar"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="vbar"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
table {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
.dot {
    height:5px;
    width:5px;
    background-color:black;
    display: inline-block;
}
.vbar {
    height:30px;
    width:5px;
    background-color: #CCCCCC;
    display: inline-block;
}
.vbar:hover {
    background-color:purple;
}
.hbar {
    height:5px;
    width:30px;
    background-color: #CCCCCC;
    display: inline-block;
}
.hbar:hover {
    background-color:purple;
}
.square {
    height:30px;
    width:30px;
    background-color: #ff88cc;
    display: inline-block;
}
.row_short {
    display: inline-block;
    position:relative;
}
.row_tall {
    display: block;
    position:relative;
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/shv289uu/)

Comment: [http://jsfiddle.net/mig1098/s4839wda/](http://jsfiddle.net/mig1098/s4839wda/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have whitespace in your code which is being rendered as spaces, creating the illusion of a 2px gap.

You can either reduce the code to a one-liner:

```
<div class="dot"></div><div class="hbar"></div>...
```

or use comments to delimit the line breaks and spaces:

```
<div class="dot"></div><!--
--><div class="hbar"></div>
```

You could also set `font-size: 0;` on a parent element (in the demo it would have to be `body` but that's a bad idea for obvious reasons), which will also collapse up all the spacing without having to edit the HTML. You'd need to reset `font-size: 1rem` to child elements if you wanted text in there, though.

Comment: An important bit missing here is that this is all caused by `display: inline-block;` (and is following the spec).

Comment: is there a display: option that I should be using for the desired result? Block will make them stack vertically, no?

Comment: I believe you could `float: left;` with `overflow: hidden;` on the parent block-level row, but I'd personally just tweak the markup, it's the lowest-maintenance thing to do. If you can avoid needing to work around something in your CSS that easily, it's probably worth just avoiding working around it :-)

Comment: Setting `1em` to a child of an element with a font size of `0` will also be zero, since `em` works like a multiplication, and multiplying with `0` will always has a result of `0`.

Comment: True; I meant `1rem` to pull from the `body` font-size